# how to deploy dll content file output with a setup project

Tags: dll, installation

Hi all I have a resources file as dll
of which CopyToOutput Directory is set to "Copy Always" & Build Action is "Content"..

When making setup for an application that uses Resources.dll
setup do not deploy Resources dll output files....

How to deploy Resources file output with this setup ??
Thanks

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/45a251f7a4.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/45a251f7a4.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend switching to using [Inno setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) for your setup file creation.

Comment: I also know other technologies like wix....but our company uses Visual studio's standart setup project for deployment....

Comment: while selecting 'Embeeded Resource' for the file that will be rendered out to bin folder during setup but for an external file other than bin needs to put output of dll to be added to setup project output folder also....